# How do I make this shorter?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have 15 roasts that I want to be randomly picked, currently I use this code for the random number:

```
const whichroast = [Math.floor(Math.random() * 15) + 1];
```

I have 15 roasts lined up like this:

```
const roast1 = "";
const roast2 = "";
const roast3 = "";
```

How do I make it so that it randomly sends the one being picked randomly? I don't want to use just if and do it for every number; is there another solution?

Comment: Use an array for heaven's sake!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep roasts into the array and by making a random number fetch it from the array.
Like

```
const roasts = ["roast1", "roast2", "roast3", "roast4", "roast5", "roast6", "roast7", "roast8", "roast9", "roast10","roast11", "roast12","roast13","roast14","roast15"]; // upto 15
console.log(roasts[Math.floor(Math.random() * roasts.length)]);
```

Comment: Do `roasts.length` instead of `15`, that way its dynamic and `15` wouldnt have to be changed each time new elements are added

Answer (score 0):

You can put every roast into an [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array). Then, you can use the [`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) function to get a random element from the array.

```js
const example = () => {

// put all your roasts in an array, separated by a comma (unlimited amount of roasts)
const roasts = ["roast1", "roast2", "roast3", "roast4", "roast5"];

// get random element
const randomRoast = roasts[Math.floor(Math.random() * roasts.length)]

console.log(randomRoast);

};
```

```html
<button onClick='example()'>Get Random Roast</button>
```